# A continuous function in $W^{1,p}(I)$ function with continuous weak derivative is a $C^1(\overline{I})$ function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In Theorem 8.2. of Brezis's book of Functional Analysis, says that a function $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ has a continuous representante $\tilde{u}$ such that
$$
\int_y^x u'(t) dt = \tilde{u}(x) - \tilde{u}(y).
$$
I'm trying to verify the following remark:
[image]

I would like to know if there is a straightforward demonstration, or whether is necessary a more sophisticated argument.

**My attempt:** Let $v$ be the continuous representative of $u'$. It is clear that $\tilde{u}$ has $v$ as its weak derivative, because given $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(I)$
$$
\int \tilde{u} \varphi' = \int u \varphi' = - \int u' \varphi = -\int v \varphi.
$$
I'm trying to prove the limite
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tilde{u}(x + h) - \tilde{u}(x)}{h}
$$
exists and equals to $v(x)$, for all $x \in I$, however it seems not to be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your formula of Theorem 8.2 it should be $\int_y^x u'(t) \, dt = \tilde{u}(x) - \tilde{u}(y)$. Then we have
$$ \lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac{\tilde{u}(x+h) -\tilde{u}(x)}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} u(t) \, dt = u'(x)$$
for a.e. $x\in \overline{I}$ by Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, and likewise
$$\lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac{\tilde{u}(x) -\tilde{u}(x-h)}{h} = u'(x)$$
for a.e. $x\in \overline{I}$. But as $u'$ is supposed to be continuous, this hold for all $x\in \overline{I}$.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question.